# jQuery toggleslide not working after ajax refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been playing around with Ajax and jQuery to generate a menu which shows the top 10 categories of items in my store, when the user click "Show More" the menu slides down revealing more categories.

The "Show More" text is called "button" and the results that are shown are called "results".

Here is the relevant code:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").on("click",function(){
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");

  });

});
</script>
```

When I click on one of the categories to refine the results it works fine, the problem comes when I click to remove the filter, the "more" toggleslide no longer works. I've read into this and I think that it's to do withing binding and the use of on()

So i've tried the following with no sucess.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").live("click",".button",function(){
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");

  });
    });
    </script>
```

and

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").on("click",".button",function(){
    $("#results").slideToggle("slow");

  });
    });
    </script>
```

I'd obviously like a fix but if someone could also explain why this isn't working it would really help with my learning jQuery / AJAX

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Can you please provide your html part?

Comment: What version of JS are you using?  --- http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's `on` syntax expects a selector and then a container:

`$('selector').on('click', 'container', function(){...`

Is `.button` a parent of `#button`?

`$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){` may be what you're after.